# How to safely assign yourself to your own delegate without ending in retain cycle?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have a class SomeTextFieldClass, that is a subclass of UITextField class. I use it for view customization on UITextField view and I would also like to use it to handle restrictions on what the user is typing , e.g. user is allowed to type in only numbers with 2 decimal places etc. For that purpose I use the delegate of UITextFieldDelegate `textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool` . When I assingn `self.delegate = self` during initialization of my SomeTextFieldClass , I can make the functionality work. However I have a strong feeling that it creates an retain cycle, and I would like to avoid that. Is there some other way how to do it? What is some best practice to use delegate methods on the class itself? Basically I just want to access the UITextField delegate methods (e.g. `shouldChangeCharactersIn`) on UITextField child class itself. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegates are 'weak' in nature. Hence the retain count does not increase by 1 when assigning the delegate. Therefore, there is no retain cycle created.

Check this out: https://medium.com/macoclock/delegate-retain-cycle-in-swift-4d9c813d0544

Comment: Delegates are **usually** weak by convention in order to avoid retain cycles. The are not weak unless you make them weak however. A better answer would be "By convention, you should make your delegate properties weak. That avoids retain cycles."

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should setup the delegate as "textfield.delegate = self" in the view controller. Then, you should handle it like;

```
extension UIViewController: SomeTextFieldClassDelegate {
  // protocol functions are here
}
```

in SomeTextFieldClass, delegate should be defined as "weak";

```
weak var delegate: SomeTextFieldClassDelegate?
```

If you provide more code, you can get better help. But it looks like there is something wrong in this code; "self.delegate = self" . I guess that you assign textfield to its own delegate.

Comment: Well, here is more info: I use textfield IBOutlet as SomeTextField class. In SomeTextField class I set some more textField view properties (cornerRadius, shadow etc.) The reason why I dont want to make UIViewController as delegate is , that I have around 15 IBOutlets of SomeTextField class in my view, therefore I would have to set UIViewController as a delegate to each of them . I tought it would be more efficient to handle SomeTextField behaviour restrictions within SomeTextField class itself by accessing self delegate methods.